# Write a few things to a session in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am learning Session function in CakePhp, and see some examples like this on cakePHP 
cookBook web site:

```
For example: 
write($mysession1, 'testing')
```

I am not sure if a session can only hold up a particular thing in it.
Is it possible to write an array to a session like:

```
mysession[0] = 'Testing0';
mysession[1] = 'Testing1';
mysession[2] = 'Testing2';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write an array to the session

```
$array = array('MyKey'=>'MyVal');
$this->Session->write('MySessionKey',$array);
```

Would write the array into the session. Alternatively you can build your array in the session.

```
$this->Session->write('My.Session.Key', $var);
```

This would essentially be, `$_SESSION['My']['Session']['Key']`